# How do databinding to a list with a derived panel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a derived panel with a list as its member. How to bind to the list from xaml?

```
class mypanel : Panel
{
    IList<int> mylist;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

```
public static DependencyProperty myListProperty;
myListProperty= DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ListSource", typeof(IList<int>), typeof(mypanel));

            var b = new Binding("ListSource") { Source = myList, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
            SetBinding(LayerSourceProperty, b);
```

SOLUTION: The following thing worked..

```
public static DependencyProperty myListProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("ListSource", typeof(IList<int>), typeof(mypanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(mylistchanged));


private static void LayerSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (mypanel) d;
    .......
}
```

Comment: Is "mylist" a dependency property ?

Comment: Yes. I have created a dependency property. I am new to C# and WPF, I aint quite sure whether I did it properly or not.

Comment: Use `Register` instead of `RegisterAttached`. And google for differences between 'dependency property' and 'attached dependency property' :)

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet Thank you. The solution that you suggested worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nicolas said, only Dependency Properties allow full Data Binding capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring a `mylist` property in your derived Panel, you would usually put the derived Panel into an [`ItemsPanelTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347175.aspx) of an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:MyPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```